# jQuery: Extend a DOM element with custom methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a couple of dom elements acting as placeholders for custom widgets. I'd like to extend them to give each type of widget a "setvalue" function like this:

`$.fn.extend($(".dial"), {
    setval: function(val) {
});`

I don't want to extend `jQuery.fn` itself as different ypes of widgets require different `setval` methods.

Is there a way to extend DOM elements of a particular type instead of extending `jQuery.fn` itself?

Comment: If you want to give them a widget function, you should implement that in your widget.

Comment: `$('.dial')` isn't a DOM element though, it's a jQuery `object`.

Comment: @Mathletics: I begin to see the problem wit my approach- that onject will be gone once the extend call has completed, right?

Comment: @andig it may last for a few method calls, but in some cases it will be lost, for example when using `.eq(n)`. Since it is unpredictable, i wouldn't suggest using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, however, said method may get lost when using other methods on said element. It would be better to implement the method on the element's data object, or on the widget itself.

```
$(".dial").each(function(){
    $(this).data("setval",$.proxy(function(val){
        this.value = sanitize(val);
    },this));
}).eq(0).data("setval")("foobar");
```

Comment: I understand the approach but it looks a little ugly. Should I rather be going in a totally different direction, e.g. as @Bergi recommended?

Comment: @andig Yes, having it be a widget method is much cleaner.

Comment: Excellent, this helped me find the right direct to http://bililite.com/blog/understanding-jquery-ui-widgets-a-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The comments above have brought me to this approach using jQuery UI:

```
var WidgetDial = {
    _init: function() { ... },

    value: function(val) { ... },
};

$.widget("ui.widgetDial", WidgetDial);
$("#dial1").widgetDial();
$("#dial1").widgetDial("value", 30);
```