# jQuery extend method on all elements in selector

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a method onto a set of elements returned from a selector using extend:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.extend($('.panel[data-refresh-url!=""][data-refresh-url]'), {
        refresh: function (successFunc) {


            // --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
            var refreshElement = $(this).data('refresh-element');
            if (refreshElement == undefined) { refreshElement = $(this).find('.panel-body'); }
            refreshElement.empty().append('<div class="spinner"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-spin fa-spinner"></i></div>');

            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).data('refresh-url'),
                type: 'post',
                data: null,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (successFunc == undefined) {
                        refreshElement.empty().append(data);
                    } else {
                        refreshElement.empty().append(successFunc(data));
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    refreshElement.empty().append('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Could not reload panel..');
                }
            });
            // --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---


        }
    });
});
```

(**Update**: I added the full method, just in case that was somehow causing the problem.)

I've tried both `$.extend` and `$.fn.extend`, but whenever I try to call `$('#element').refresh()`, I get `refresh is not a function`.

I've changed the approach over to use `bind('refresh')` instead, and all then works, but I need to pass in a function which executes on successful refresh, and I'm under the impression I can't do that that way.

I'm really not too familiar with jQuery - what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misusing `$.extend`, totally. `$.extend` is used to merge two objects together, and can obviously be used to *extend*  one main object with a auxiliary one, like the one you've created with curly braces and the single property `refresh`.

Now, in this case you're trying to extend the **return value** of `$('.panel[data-refresh-url!=""][data-refresh-url]')`, which is something temporary. Even if you had it in a variable, like this:

```
var $buttons = $('.panel[data-refresh-url!=""][data-refresh-url]');

$.extend($buttons, { /...
```

It would just add a method `refresh` to the `$buttons` object, not to the matching elements themselves.

On the other hand, if you use `$.fn.extend`, you'll be effectively creating a jQuery plugin and that will add a method `refresh` to every object returned by `$`, that's not what you want I'm guessing.

At the end of the day, you could manually add the method to every matched element using a loop:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $buttons = $('.panel[data-refresh-url!=""][data-refresh-url]');

    for (var i = 0; i < $buttons.length; ++i)
    {
        $.extend($buttons[i], {
            refresh: function (successFunc) 
            {
                alert("Hey, I'm a button");            
            }
        });
    }

    // TESTING

    $('.panel[data-refresh-url!=""][data-refresh-url]')[0].refresh();
});
```

Comment: Ah, that rather explains the lack of examples of doing this online.. The last part there actually sounds something like what I want to do - I have a ton of panels that I want to add this functionality to. EDIT: Oh, so is the problem that I'm trying to add it to a collection of items, but it's OK if I do it item by item?

Comment: Nope, the problem is the same if you use extend for a single object. Take a close look, I'm using `$buttons[i]`. When I index the object returned by `$` like an array, it returns the actual element in that page. That's the object you want to extend, like in my example.

Comment: Take this: if you do `$(#foo)` and work with it, that's the jQuery object. If you use `$(#foo)[0]`, that's the actual HTML element.

Comment: Oh right, I'm with you - I had tried using `each(function` but thinking about it that'll still be wrapped I assume?

Comment: Well, if inside the `each` you work with `this` instead of `$(this)`, you will be working with the HTML element. This works: http://codepad.org/hhCJrxOc

Comment: I don't know what I'm missing :( this is what I have: [codepad](http://codepad.org/idi4rdsd) - I'm using console.log both sides, and it's definitely both applying the extend and firing the refresh() on the same element, but still `refresh is not a function`

Comment: Where does it get called? When you call it, you should use the brackets as well, check the last line in my example.

Comment: Argh - sorry, that's the one - I was calling it via `$ref.refresh();`.. thank you very much for your all your help.

Answer (score 1):

What you're wanting to do is stick a `refresh` method onto a (specific) set of `HTMLParagraphElement`. To do this in vanilla JS, you'd do something like:

```
HTMLParagraphElement.prototype.refresh = function(){
    alert('f');
}

$('p').click(function(){
    this.refresh();
});
```

Note how you call `this.refresh()`, instead of `$(this).refresh()`.

One principal of jQuery is that it encapsulates any new methods within itself - it doesn't extend existing DOM objects. As such, `$.extend` wont work the way you want it to.

I (*think*) what's happening is you're getting a reference to the element wrapped in a jQuery object by doing $(selector). You're then extending that object, but not actually adding anything to the underlying object. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/1a4zhwou/3/) shows that you're $.extend'ing the object in that scope, but then you've lost any changes when you come to call the method (e.g. when you bind a `click` handler).

There's a few different ways of achieveing what you're trying to do. The simplest would be to use [$.data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the function, and call it through there. [Here's a fiddle of that](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/1a4zhwou/2/).

If you really want to extend the HTMLParagraphElement, you can do it by calling `$.extend` on the `prototype` object. [This blog post](http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-extending-html-dom-elements-with-extend/) explains it in detail, but you essentially just do the following.

```
$.extend(HTMLParagraphElement.prototype, {
    refresh: function() {
        alert('Refresh called!');
    }
});

$('.panel').find('[data-refresh-url!=""][data-refresh-url]').click(function(){
    this.refresh();
});
```

I personally believe that you shouldn't modify objects that you don't own - so I'd go with the `$.data` approach. Alternatively, jQuery UI uses a good pattern which is briefly explained in [this post on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706041/jquery-extend-a-dom-element-with-custom-methods).

Comment: The `$.data` approach looks interesting - I had tried `bind` but was having some difficulty getting the data back and forth. I'll def try this out, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to add a new method to jQuery objects, have you tried simply using `$.fn.methodName=function(){}`?

```
$.fn.newMethod=function(){
    console.log(this); // jQuery object
}
$('#element').newMethod();
```

Comment: I had intended to add it only to the objects under that specific selector - just because it hunts out other panel data attributes and elements under the main. I guess I could just do those checks just inside the function though..